# Difference between seasonality-adjusted data and the trend component

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, seasonality, trend

After decomposing the time series, what is the intuitive difference between seasonality-adjusted data and the trend component (from decomposition)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An additive time series decomposition expresses a time series as
$$y_t = T_t + S_t + R_t$$
where $T_t$ is the trend component, $S_t$ is the seasonal component and $R_t$ is the remainder.

The seasonally adjusted series is given by $y_t - S_t = T_t + R_t$. That is, it is equal to the sum of the trend and remainder components.

See https://otexts.com/fpp3/components.html for more details.